# C program to read a file and print all the lines that are mentioned in an array

Tags: c

```
const int size = 1;
int lineSeekArray[size];
lineSeekArray[0] = 0;
lineSeekArray[1] = 1;
static const char filename[] = "testfile.txt";

FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
int i =0;
if ( file != NULL )
{
   char line [ 328 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
   while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) {/* read a line */

     i++;
     if(i  == 9)
     {
        fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
     }

   }

  fclose ( file );
```

right now my code prints the line number 9 of a file.  is there any efficient way to print the line numbers that are in the array.
basically, if I have array with two integers like  0 and 1. 
i want to print only those two lines. 
(the array size is dynamic based on user input number).

thanks

Comment: Use a loop in place of the `if (i == 9)` line?  `for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++) if (lineSeekArray[j] == i) fputs(line, stdout);` — for example.  You have array overflow problems (`size` is `1`, so `lineSeekArray[1]` is writing out of bounds — I used `MAX` for the number of entries in the array).

Comment: thanks for quick response, I thought of doing that. using this for loop in a while loop would might be little inefficient. is there any better solution ?

Comment: Have you measured it?  You could arrange to delete entries from the array when matched, which would improve performance, but if you’ve got problems implementing the basics, worrying about performance is “premature optimization” which is the root of much evil in C code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I take your point but I am new to C so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array of line numbers is sorted in ascending order, you could do it by modifying your code as follows:

```
int lineNumbers[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
size_t numElements = sizeof(lineNumbers)/sizeof(lineNumbers[0]);
size_t currentIndex = 0;
...
while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) {/* read a line */
    i++;
    if (i  == lineNumbers[currentIndex]) {
        fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
        if (++currentIndex == numElements) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This lets you determine if `i` is equal to the next desired line without walking through the array repeatedly.

Comment: thanks so much. That's a solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you make sure that `lineSeekArray` is sorted so that it's values are in ascending order, then you could just use a single loop from 0 to the maximum value in `lineSeekArray`. Now you'll only try to read as many lines as necessary. You'll also avoid having to loop through `lineSeekArray`.

You can't avoid having to read every line from the beginning of a text file though. If you stored it in binary format you'd have random access capability. That's because you could just calculate the starting location of every line and read it directly.

```
Initialising j = 0. 
for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){ 
    1. Attempt to read line from file and exit loop on failure.
    2. If i == lineSeekArray[j] --> print line, increment j, exit loop if j >= size
}
```